# Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to instanciate a chaincode that was previously working ( last year ) in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.4

Chaincode installation works:

```
$ export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org0.example.com:7051
$ peer chaincode install -n main -v 1.0.0 -p main -l golang


...
2021-01-11 16:50:03.308 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 70a Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

But when I try to instantiate with:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n main -v 1.0.0  -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -C mychannel --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c '{"Args":["GetMeasuresBetween","2019-03-29T12:00:00Z", "2019-03-29T14:00:00Z"]}' -P ""
```

I am getting:

```
root@e16f0ae0376a:/etc/hyperledger/artifacts# peer chaincode instantiate -n main -v 1.0.0  -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -C ekate --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c '{"Args":["GetMeasuresBetween","2019-03-29T12:00:00Z", "2019-03-29T14:00:00Z"]}' -P ""
2021-01-11 16:54:48.948 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2021-01-11 16:54:48.949 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 002 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2021-01-11 16:54:48.949 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 003 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 007 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 008 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2021-01-11 16:54:48.950 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string 
2021-01-11 16:54:48.951 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00a Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2021-01-11 16:54:48.951 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2021-01-11 16:54:48.951 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00c Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2021-01-11 16:54:48.951 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00d Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.952 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00e Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.952 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00f Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.952 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 010 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.953 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 011 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.953 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.953 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 013 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2021-01-11 16:54:48.954 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 014 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.954 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 015 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.954 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 016 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[Default:SW PKCS11:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Hash:<nil> Label:<nil> Library:<nil> Pin:<nil> Security:<nil>] SW:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:] Hash:SHA2 Security:256]]]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/keystore]...done
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.955 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/signcerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/signcerts/Admin@org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/cacerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/cacerts/ca.org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/admincerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 023 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 024 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlscacerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 027 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 028 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 029 crls folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.956 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a Loading NodeOUs
2021-01-11 16:54:48.957 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02b Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2021-01-11 16:54:48.957 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02c Creating Cache-MSP instance
2021-01-11 16:54:48.957 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02d Created new local MSP
2021-01-11 16:54:48.957 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02e Setting up MSP instance org0MSP
2021-01-11 16:54:48.957 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 02f Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:54:48.958 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:54:48.958 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 031 Loading private key [7d42c8d928dc41fab8c642ae8c3fa6ff503f05aa662a1ad0a8d8bd30d946a648] at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/keystore/7d42c8d928dc41fab8c642ae8c3fa6ff503f05aa662a1ad0a8d8bd30d946a648_sk]...
2021-01-11 16:54:48.958 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:54:48.958 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 033 Signing identity expires at 2031-01-09 16:13:00 +0000 UTC
2021-01-11 16:54:48.960 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 034 parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:54:48.960 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 035 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:54:48.960 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 036 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org0.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.960 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 037 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:54:48.960 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 038 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002679f0, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:54:48.963 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 039 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002679f0, READY
2021-01-11 16:54:48.966 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03a parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:54:48.966 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03b scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:54:48.966 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03c ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org0.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.966 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03d ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:54:48.966 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00024d6a0, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:54:48.969 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00024d6a0, READY
2021-01-11 16:54:48.970 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2021-01-11 16:54:48.970 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 041 parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:54:48.970 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 042 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:54:48.971 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 043 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer0.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:54:48.971 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 044 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:54:48.971 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 045 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003f1cf0, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:54:48.974 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 046 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003f1cf0, READY
2021-01-11 16:54:48.974 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 047 Using default escc
2021-01-11 16:54:48.974 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 048 Using default vscc
2021-01-11 16:54:48.975 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 049 Sign: plaintext: 0ABB070A6308031A0C08D885F2FF0510...305A0A000A04657363630A0476736363 
2021-01-11 16:54:48.975 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04a Sign: digest: B9D5E2703F2022EBC2D4DADD38E9703FB0096B49832C69F46B4361EB8E649DFF 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 2
root@e16f0ae0376a:/etc/hyperledger/artifacts# peer chaincode instantiate -n main -v 1.0.0  -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -C ekate --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c '{"Args":["GetMeasuresBetween","2019-03-29T12:00:00Z", "2019-03-29T14:00:00Z"]}' -P ""
root@e16f0ae0376a:/etc/hyperledger/artifacts# peer chaincode instantiate -n main -v 1.0.0  -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -C ekate --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c '{"Args":["GetMeasuresBetween","2019-03-29T12:00:00Z", "2019-03-29T14:00:00Z"]}' -P ""
2021-01-11 16:58:17.641 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2021-01-11 16:58:17.641 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 002 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2021-01-11 16:58:17.642 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 003 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.642 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.642 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.643 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.643 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 007 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.643 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 008 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.644 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2021-01-11 16:58:17.644 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00a Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.644 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.645 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00c Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.645 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00d Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.645 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00e Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.646 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00f Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2021-01-11 16:58:17.646 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 010 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2021-01-11 16:58:17.646 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 011 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2021-01-11 16:58:17.647 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2021-01-11 16:58:17.647 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 013 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2021-01-11 16:58:17.647 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 014 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2021-01-11 16:58:17.647 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 015 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2021-01-11 16:58:17.647 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 016 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string 
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[Default:SW PKCS11:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Hash:<nil> Label:<nil> Library:<nil> Pin:<nil> Security:<nil>] SW:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:] Hash:SHA2 Security:256]]]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/keystore]...done
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/signcerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/signcerts/Admin@org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:58:17.648 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/cacerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/cacerts/ca.org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/admincerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 023 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 024 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlscacerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org0.example.com-cert.pem
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 027 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 028 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls
2021-01-11 16:58:17.649 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 029 crls folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.650 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a Loading NodeOUs
2021-01-11 16:58:17.650 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02b Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2021-01-11 16:58:17.650 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02c Creating Cache-MSP instance
2021-01-11 16:58:17.650 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02d Created new local MSP
2021-01-11 16:58:17.650 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02e Setting up MSP instance org0MSP
2021-01-11 16:58:17.651 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 02f Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICUTCCAfigAwIBAgIRAKsU0VyX5WNuGHkPXXqC1kgwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwczEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG
cmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzAuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMTE2Nh
Lm9yZzAuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMjEwMTExMTYxMzAwWhcNMzEwMTA5MTYxMzAw
WjBzMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMN
U2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMC5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTEcMBoGA1UE
AxMTY2Eub3JnMC5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IA
BC9j8xLVAMwlGQEYndt4+QDserZU3iOd5fRkXtWlMP55T+fsn2/M1DVKocOu9Dp1
y+px1d3QnPjXpkpNnGGC4QOjbTBrMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBpjAdBgNVHSUEFjAU
BggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zApBgNVHQ4EIgQg
DQv1QJQY6ObnNkoCcZ/UtMj63vB29/RU+TuVib1Ova8wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAw
RAIgdWU0w63Su008mJcNyLUEEAkWhKHY0n+CTfAWswH+DLsCIAN291AQWhaSF/Lv
Suo3xv/65wUzKr0Ez30Rk1dML8SI
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:58:17.651 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:58:17.651 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 031 Loading private key [7d42c8d928dc41fab8c642ae8c3fa6ff503f05aa662a1ad0a8d8bd30d946a648] at [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp/keystore/7d42c8d928dc41fab8c642ae8c3fa6ff503f05aa662a1ad0a8d8bd30d946a648_sk]...
2021-01-11 16:58:17.652 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2021-01-11 16:58:17.652 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 033 Signing identity expires at 2031-01-09 16:13:00 +0000 UTC
2021-01-11 16:58:17.654 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 034 parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:58:17.654 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 035 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:58:17.654 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 036 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org0.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.654 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 037 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:58:17.654 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 038 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000237300, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:58:17.657 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 039 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000237300, READY
2021-01-11 16:58:17.660 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03a parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:58:17.660 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03b scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:58:17.660 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03c ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org0.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.660 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03d ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:58:17.661 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000236840, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:58:17.663 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000236840, READY
2021-01-11 16:58:17.664 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2021-01-11 16:58:17.665 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 041 parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-11 16:58:17.665 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 042 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-11 16:58:17.665 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 043 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer0.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-11 16:58:17.665 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 044 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-11 16:58:17.665 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 045 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00039dce0, CONNECTING
2021-01-11 16:58:17.668 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 046 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00039dce0, READY
2021-01-11 16:58:17.668 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 047 Using default escc
2021-01-11 16:58:17.668 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 048 Using default vscc
2021-01-11 16:58:17.668 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 049 Sign: plaintext: 0ABB070A6308031A0C08A987F2FF0510...305A0A000A04657363630A0476736363 
2021-01-11 16:58:17.668 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04a Sign: digest: E866534EDF3BB474A754DDC4A0A5E598F1275F7296730E0558295BD1509C43E2 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 2
```

I get all this detail because I have set several debug variable:

```
export FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
export CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
export CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
```

What does this mean ? Does it mean I have to check my code. This same chaincode was deploying last year with no problem, so it seems weird. Nevertheless, I can successfully instantiate the default chaincode.

My issue is that I can't interpret what is the meaning of the error. If this is a code error, is it possible to see the stack error ? In other words, what should I do to debug this one ?

Comment: Is there a chaincode image that was instantiated before? Does it work the same even after completely cleaning the docker containers and images for the `main` chaincode?

Comment: Is there a chaincode image that was instantiated before --> Yes, I have instantiated the 2 chaincodes, given as examples in the project. but the name of the chaincode and the version are differents

Comment: Does it work the same even after completely cleaning the docker containers and images for the main chaincode --> How should I do the cleaning ???

Comment: If the name and version are different, there is actually no problem, but the way to clean it up is to delete the existing docker container and image. `docker rm -f <your_chaincode_container>` / `docker rmi <your_chaincode_image>`

Comment: Also, pay attention to the volume of the dokcer. If your statedb is goleveldb, there may be volumes left to be deleted before. When lowering the entire network, clear the volume by giving docker-compose's `-v` option. Alternatively, you can delete unnecessary volumes through `docker volume prune` after the network is down.

Comment: Now I see a strange option in `instantiate` command. I am curious about the reason why the endorsement policy was set to "". If you don't want to use it, just delete the `-P ""`.

Comment: I will create a fresh network, and drop my old VM. So everything should be clean. Also, I could remove the -P param, you are right. I do use leveldb